# An idea for analysis of object-oriented code

Tags: c#, oop, code-analysis

If I could do magic I would conjure up a C# code analysis tool; let's call it `XYZ`. Here's an example of some code you could give as input to `XYZ`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int myInt;

    [Functional]
    public int GetDoubleOfMyInt()
    {
        return 2*myInt;
    }

    [SideEffect: myInt] 
    public void IncrementMyInt()
    {
        myInt++;
    }
}
```

Notice the tags on the two methods. `XYZ` would verify that `GetDoubleOfMyInt()` is indeed purely functional (in the sense that it merely computes an integer) and that `IncrementMyInt` has the side effect of assigning a value to `myInt`. If you swapped the two tags `XYZ` would issue two errors.

My questions: 
1. Does something ressembling `XYZ` actually exist?
2. If you were asked to implement it, where would you start?

Comment: Have you heard of [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992)?

Comment: `Functional` isn't particular descriptive. Consider something like "pure" or "no side effects". Also note that there are data structures which are purely functional to the outside but make heavy use of mutability under the hood - veryfing correctness of *those* would be more useful, but also much harder.

Comment: Posting this as a comment because it's not really an answer, but if you have the time and inclination you could take a look at how Ada works and perhaps draw some inspiration; it separates procedures (which may modify their input) from functions (which may not), and has several compiler pragmas such as the Pure pragma, which signifies that the code has no side effects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code Contracts essentially does what you are asking. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992)

Code Contracts allow you to decorate your code with attributes and calls that allow the compiler and IDE to statically analyse your code. You can find Code Contracts within the `System.Diagnostics.Contracts` namespace, but to take advantage of full static type checking, you need at least the Premium edition SKU of Visual Studio (I think).

A quick example, your `Functional` attribute essentially is the same as `Pure`:

```
[Pure]
public void GetMessage() { return _message; }
```

Which tells the analyser that the method makes no state changes. You can also do pre and post conditions on your methods, e.g.:

```
public void WriteMessage(string message)
{
    Contract.Requires(message != null);
}
```

There is a lot of depth in Code Contracts, and worth a good reading.

Answer (score 2):

The [static analysis tool NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) does pretty much what you are describing. Have a look at this default Code Query Rule that find methods that where *pure* (because tagged with a *PureAttribute*) and that are not *pure* anymore:

```
// <Name>Regression on pure methods</Name>
WARN IF Count > 0 IN SELECT METHODS WHERE 
  HasAttribute "OPTIONAL:NDepend.CQL.PureAttribute" AND 
  ( ChangesObjectState OR ChangesTypeState ) AND
  NbLinesOfCode > 0

// A method is pure if its execution doesn’t change 
// the value of any instance or static field. 
// Pure methods naturally simplify code by limiting 
// side-effects.
// See some explanations on immutability - purity and 
// how NDepend supports it here:
// http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/01/13/immutable-types-understand-them-and-use-them.aspx

// NDepend.CQL.PureAttribute is defined in the 
// redistributable assembly $NDependInstallDir$\Lib\NDepend.CQL.dll
// You can define your own attribute to tag 'pure' methods.
```

Notice that you can use your own *PureAttribute* instead of the one specified by default in the rule, just specify your attribute *namespace.nameAttribute*.

Notice that the [CQL (Code Query Language)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) clauses *ChangesObjectState* and *ChangesTypeState* returns true for methods that assign an *instance (object)* or a *static (type)* field.